# You have an error in your SQL syntax near '<!

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Trying to relocate a Wordpress DB and are running in to this issue all the time.

Been trying all the normal stuff to get it working optimizing, repairing etc and also try to import it with several tools (Sequel pro etc ) and over ssh.

Have the issue occurring over several tables and can see that other's have had the same. Because i can't import any copy i would need some expertise advice how to solve this either in phpmyadmin or ssh.

**Error message is**

```
  #mysql -u -p db < /tmp/file.sql

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 109088: You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
> for the right syntax to use near '<!
> <div class="error"><h1>Error</h1> <p><strong>SQL query:</strong> <a href=' at line 1
```

Don't really know how to approach it because i find this all over the DB 
like

`<image:caption><![CDATA`

Any advice?

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question and actually show the query.

Comment: Yes , you have error in SQL , I know that ! But Where/What is SQL you have written ?

Comment: `<a href='` <-- unescaped single quote perhaps: Use a parametrized insert.

Comment: What would be the way to solve it, Am not that in to sql db so any advice would be sweet!  @AlexK.

Comment: Search and replace. <a href=' to <a href=" ?

Comment: It is there "mysql -u -p db < /tmp/file.sql"

Answer (score 0):

Since "all the normal stuff" isn't working...

I'm going to take a guess, you are a running something to "copy" the contents of a database table, or you're doing some sort of "dump" or "export" that creates SQL statements.

And the SQL statements that are running against the target are throwing an error.

We can't tell (from where we're sitting and what we're seeing) what it is you are actually doing, we're just guessing.

The two most likely possibilities:

Whatever tool you are using isn't expecting that the column values being copied might contain values that need to be "escaped" if that value is incorporated in the text of a SQL statement. For example, suppose I have a column value like this:

```
   I'd like a pony
```

and If I grab that value and I naively stick that into the text of a SQL statement, without regard for any characters it might contain, e.g.

```
   INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('I'd like a pony');
```

If I try to execute that statement, MySQL is going to throw a syntax error. MySQL is  going to see a string literal with a value of `'I'` (the single quote that is part of the string is now being seen as the end of the string literal. MySQL is going to flag a syntax error on what follows `d like a pony`.

When we take a value and build a SQL statement from it, we have to properly escape the values. In this example, the insert statement to reproduce that string value could look like this:

```
  INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('I''d like a pony');
                                  ^^
```

If this is what's happening, you can be thankful that the column values didn't include something more nefarious...

```
  Robert'); DROP TABLE students; --
```

But without seeing the actual SQL statement that is being executed, this is just a guess at what is causing the issue.

---

Is there some kind of guide or some instructions that you are following to "relocate a Wordpress DB" which documents "all the normal stuff" that you are doing?

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Question was edited to add this information:

```
  mysql -u -p db < /tmp/file.sql
```

What's important here is the contents of `file.sql`.

The problem is most likely in the part of "all the normal stuff" is producing that file. That part is effectively broken because it's not expecting that an extracted column value can contain a single quote character, and is not properly escaping the value before it's incorporated into the text of a SQL INSERT statement.